# Необходимо перенести выпадающее меню на передний план

Tags: css, css3, веб-программирование, frontend

Возникла проблема с выпадающем меню, его нужно перенести при нажатии на передний план, но мешает элемент с позиционированием sticky под ним, вот сам сайт - https://0398-46-172-28-69.eu.ngrok.io/, буду безмерно благодарен за помощь

[image: вот скриншот проблемы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно указать для `.main-head` `z-index:1` или больше.